# Android library Correct usage of V4 Support Library Confusion

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library, support-v4

I am trying to reduce the apk size for my project and for that I am trying to remove having the entire support-v4 library dependency, but rather only adding the modules I need for my project.  According to below, it seems possible to only include the modules I need instead of importing the entire support-v4 library(1).  My current project is using support-v4(entire library) in gradle.  Whenever I use, in my activities classes like ActivityCompat on the import header I see: "import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;".  My confusion is that I have removed the support-v4 library from gradle and only including the module needed for the ActivityCompat class, that is: "com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0".  Why when I try to use ActivityCompat class it is still importing the same "import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;"?  Is this expected?

From Android reference: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html

> (1)"Note: Prior to Support Library revision 24.2.0, there was a single
>   v4 support library. That library was divided into multiple modules to
>   improve efficiency. For backwards compatibility, if you list
>   support-v4 in your Gradle script, your APK will include all of the v4
>   modules. However, to reduce APK size, we recommend that you just list
>   the specific modules your app needs."

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;<--regardless of whether I include support-v4 or only the module needed from android(com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0) same import is still being used.
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        ActivityCompat
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lint may help you.

Answer (score -1):

Per the [ActivityCompat documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html) (specifically, in the upper right):

> belongs to Maven artifact `com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0`

So the class you are using is in the `support-compat` dependency, as expected. The naming for the dependencies is only loosely related to the naming of the packages the classes are in (obviously, changing the packages for the classes would break everyone that upgrades, which probably wouldn't be ideal).

Comment: You didn't tell me anything I didn't know already. Go back and re-read the question.

Comment: You're including `support-compat`. `android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat` is part of `support-compat`. You asked if that's expected and it is.

Comment: Okay, that is more clear.  However, even if I remove the module(support-compat) I am still able to find the class, that is, when I try to use that class(ActivityCompat) I can still use it even though that dependency was removed from the gradle.  I notice the jars for both the support-v4 and the individual modules are in the library folder within projects.

Comment: You should probably [view your whole dependency tree](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view-dependency-tree) to see what transitive dependencies are being pulled in by the libraries you specifically declare.

Comment: So, even though support-design includes support v7 and support-v7 includes support-v4, there is a chance support-v7 depends on support-v4 or that support-design depends on support-v7 or support-v4?

Comment: Looks like you're referring to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68820009) where `design` incorrectly depends on the entirety of `support-v4` rather than only what it needs. Looks like the issue is marked as fixed for the next release already, thankfully!

Comment: Didn't know it was marked as an issue.  So that means until today there is still a chance of cyclic dependency right? and we have to include the support-v4 and support-v7? even having support-design.

Comment: There's no cyclic dependencies. The dependency tree tells you exactly what each dependency pulls in. `design` depends on `appcompat-v7` and `support-v4`. `appcompat-v7` depends on a subset of the `support-v4` libraries. AppCompat's dependencies are already as small as they can be, so really the only thing you could optimize is `design` erroneously pulling in `support-v4` when it comes to Support Libraries. You really need to look at your dependency tree to see what else pulls in `support-v4`.

Comment: All I am trying to do is remove support-v4 from my project and only including the indpendent modules from support-v4 such as support-compat, support-coreui, etc.  However, if support-design adds support-v4 automatically this doesn't seem possible.  I have removed support-v4 from gradle and appcompat-v7 and all the classes from support-v4 are still found in my project by just keeping support-design.